# Find all $m,n \in \mathbb N$ Such that $3(2^m)+4=n^2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Find All $n,m\in \mathbb N$ Such that $3(2^m)+4=n^2$

I’ve tried to plug some values of $m$, and it turns up that the only valid values is $$m\in \{2,5,6\}.$$

So once i saw that i tried to prove that it doesn’t exist a solution to the equation $\forall m\geq7$. But i have no idea how to prove this.

**Something i’m not sure whether it’s true:**

$$3(2^m)+4=n^2 \iff3(2^m+1)=n^2-1 \\ \iff 3(2^m+1)=(n+1)(n-1)$$

Thus $3\mid (n+1)(n-1) $, But since $3$ is a prime and $\gcd(n+1,n-1)=1$ or $2 \implies$
$3\mid n+1$ or $3\mid n-1$ What’s next?

Comment: You can observe that $ n $ should be even.

Comment: It is easier to work with $ 3 \times 2^m = (n-2)(n+2)$, as you can clearly decide where the prime factors should go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Here's a suggested approach. If you're stuck, explain where you're stuck and what you've tried.)

- Factor it as $ 3 \times 2^m = (n-2) ( n+2)$.
- Hence $ \{ n-2, n+2 \} = \{ 3 \times 2^a, 2^b \}$.
- Hence $  3 \times 2^a = 2^b \pm 4 $.
- If $ b = 0, 1, 2$, what can we say? What are the solutions with these small cases?

> $3 \times 2^a = 1+4, 2+4, 4+4$ (cannot take negative branch).
>  So we get $ b=1, a = 1 \Rightarrow 2 \times 6 = 3\times 2^2  $.

- If $ b \geq 3$, what can we say?

> RHS is a multiple of 4 but not 8, so $ a = 2$.
>  $3 \times 4 = 2^b \pm 4$, which gives us $b=3, 4$.
>  $a = 2, b = 3 \Rightarrow 8\times 12 = 3\times 2^5 .$
>  $a = 2, b = 4 \Rightarrow 12 \times 16 = 3\times 2^6 . $

In conclusion, we have solutions only when $ m = 2, 5, 6$.

Answer (score 1):

**In respect of the stated comment, I add our second case (and so the whole solution) I left for OP to solve.**

First, check $m=1$.

If $m≥2, m-2=k$ and $n=2n_1$, then

$$3×2^{k}+1=n_1^2, n_1≥2$$

**Case $-1.$**

$n_1=3a+1$, where $a≥1.$

$$3×2^k=9a^2+6a$$

$$2^k=3a^2+2a$$

$$a≥1 \Longrightarrow \begin{cases} a=2b \\ k≥3 \end{cases}$$

$$2^k=12b^2+4b$$

$$2^{k-2}=3b^2+b=b(3b+1)$$

$$b=2^x, 3b+1=2^y$$

If $x≥1$, then we get $3b+1≥7$ and $3b+1$ is an odd number, which gives a contradiction.

So, we deduce that $x=0.$

Then, we can check $n_1=3a+2$ by the same way.

Of course, $n_1=3a$ is impossible.

---

The method of looking at our second case is the same as the first one, as I mentioned earlier.

**Case $-2.$**

$n_1=3a+2$, where $a≥0.$

First, check $a=0$. If, $a≥1$ then

$$3×2^k+1=9a^2+12a+4$$

$$2^k=3a^2+4a+1, a≥1$$

$$a≥1 \Longrightarrow \begin{cases} a=2b-1 \\ k≥3 \end{cases}$$

We have,

$$2^k=3(2b-1)^2+4(2b-1)+1, b≥1$$

$$2^k=12b^2-4b$$

$$2^{k-2}=3b^2-b=b(3b-1)$$

$$b=2^x, 3b-1=2^y$$

If $x≥1$, then we get $3b-1≥5$ and $3b-1$ is an odd number, which gives a contradiction.

So, we deduce that $x=0.$

Finally, backward all the steps and you will find all required integer values ​​of $m$ and $n.$

Comment: Why is $3b+1$ an odd number? Are you assuming that $b$ must be even? EG with $ m = 6, k = 4, b = 1, 3b+1 = 4$ is even (and this yield a valid solution).

Comment: @CalvinLin Please check my proof correctly. By the way, downvote is everyone's natural right.  But this downvote doesn't seem fair at all.

Comment: Ah, I see that you had $ x \geq 1$, sorry I missed that. Let me read through this again.

Comment: K, I removed my downvote (had to edit your answer in order to change my vote). I didn't upvote because the $n=3a+2$ case doesn't quite seem to be the same way. I get to $2^k = (3a+1)(a+1)$, but can't quite force out that parity argument, since both terms are even when $a$ is odd. How did you proceed? (I used a different argument, bounding $3 \times 2^x - 2$ between successive powers of 2 for large enough $x$.)

Comment: @CalvinLin Well, please accept my answer as a partial answer for now.  I should be at work in 1 hour.  Unfortunately, my job has nothing to do with mathematics.  If I can add the other part of the answer without leaving the house, I'll do it.  If I can't add it, I'll do it in the next hours.  Now accept my answer as partial.  I am grateful for your patience.

Comment: @CalvinLin I had the opportunity to add the solution now.  Our second case is almost the same as the first.  (as I mentioned before)

Comment: Oh nice, thanks!

Comment: @CalvinLin You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

My english is not that good, I will try to explay the main steps, I hope you can understand.

$3(2^m)=(n^2-4)=(n-2)(n+2)$

so $3|n-2$ or $3|n+2$.

If $3|n-2$, then $n=3x+2$ for some $x\geq0$.

So, going back to the first equation with $n=3x+2$, we have $2^m=x(3x+4)$. So

$x=2^k$, for some $k$ satisfying $0\leq k \leq m$.

This means that. we have $2^{k-m}=3.2^k+4$, and so,
$3.2^k=4(2^{k-m-2}+1)$.

Finally $3.2^{k-2}=2^{k-m-2}+1$. And you analyse the conditions to both sides be odd or even.

The same idea, you can work with the case 3|n+2.

Answer (score -1):

**hint**

It is easy to check that $ m $ satisfies
$$m\ge 2.$$

but

$$3.2^m=(n+2)(n-2)$$
with $ n $ even.

So
$$(n+2)|3.2^m $$
and by Gauss Theorem
$$(n+2)|2^m$$

Comment: How does that help? Could $ n = 2^8 - 2 $?